# High order PDEs

Tags: math, numerical, pde

I'm trying to solve a 6th-order nonlinear PDE (1D) with fixed boundary values (extended Fisher-Kolmogorov - EFK).  After failing with FTCS, next attempt is MoL (either central in space or FEM) using e.g. LSODES.

How can this be implemented? Using Python/C + OpenMP so far, but need some pointers
to do this efficiently.

EFK with additional 6th order term:

```
u_t = d u_6x - g u_4x + u_xx + u-u^3
```

where d, g are real coefficients.

u(x,0) = exp(-x^2/16),
ux = 0 on boundary

domain is [0,300] and dx << 1 since i'm looking for pattern formations (subject to the values
of d, g)

I hope this is sufficient information.

Comment: FTCS is bound to fail unless you use a 6th order discretization for the laplacian and the 4th derivative. What did not work ? I don't know the difficulties with this particular equation (the u - u^3 term plays probably some havoc on the stability of any scheme however, and there should be a condition on d and g for the equation to have a solution), so any extra info would be good. Also try mathoverflow.net (with as much detail as possible, and especially *why* the methods you tried did not work).

Comment: Some quick check into the litterature seems to indicate that a FDM *should* work. Don't even bother to try explicit methods though.

Comment: [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com) would probably be a better choice than Mathoverflow, which is predominantly theoretical IMO.

Comment: @jonsca: there are some numerical analysts on mathoverflow, and this equation is research-level. I don't know about the folks of Math.SE, but this is maybe worth a try too.

Comment: @Alexandre Certainly that's true.  I have no doubts that this is a high caliber problem, I've just found the math and stats SE sites more user friendly.  Anyway, just my $0.02, sorry if I interjected.

Answer (score 3):

All PDE solutions like this will ultimately end up being expressed using linear algebra in your program, so the trick is to figure out how to get the PDE into that form before you start coding.

Finite element methods usually begin with a weighted residual method.  Non-linear equations will require a linear approximation and iterative methods like Newton-Raphson.  I would recommend that you start there.

Yours is a transient solution, so you'll have to do time stepping.  You can either use an explicit method and live with the small time steps that stability limits will demand or an implicit method, which will force you to do a matrix inversion at each step.

I'd do a Fourier analysis first of the linear piece to get an idea of the stability requirements.

The only term in that equation that makes it non-linear is the last one: -u^3.  Have you tried starting by leaving that term off and solving the linear equation that remains?

UPDATE: Some additional thoughts prompted by comments:

I understand how important the `u^3` term is.  Diffusion is a 2nd order derivative w.r.t. space, so I wouldn't be so certain that a 6th order equation will follow suit.  My experience with PDEs comes from branches of physics that don't have 6th order equations, so I honestly don't know what the solution might look like.  I'd solve the linear problem first to get a feel for it.

As for stability and explicit methods, it's dogma that the stability limits placed on time step size makes them likely to fail, but the probability isn't 1.0.  I think map reduce and cloud computing might make an explicit solution more viable than it was even 10-20 years ago.  Explicit dynamics have become a mainstream way to solve difficult statics problems, because they don't require a matrix inversion.

Comment: my bet is that the -u^3 here is exactly what makes this equation difficult (after all, the equation models phase transitions !). If you leave it out, you get a vanilla diffusion equation (a quite exotic one, I confess). Also, Von Neumann analysis will probably tell you that any explicit method will fail. Your advice is generally sound, but here the difficulties are likely not in the implementation method.